# Mercurial SSH certificate issue

Tags: mercurial

I am seeing this error on Ubuntu:
hg clone https://...
abort: error: _ssl.c:326: error:0B084009:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:PEM lib

I tried clearing ~/.ssh but have had no luck connecting to the mercurial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonfa has the right idea.  You have 2 options:

1) Get a clean certificate from another linux installation and point to that ca-certificates.crt file.

2) Replace your /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt with a old copy or one from a clean linux install.

Comment: looks like my ubuntu 10.10 certificate file worked in my 9.10 installation